# Print a value from 2d array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program that allows a user to add values to a 2d array and then search the array and display the value. The information is being stored properly, but all I can get to display is the animal name and not the food. Before I get grilled I've searched and implemented a bunch of different methods trying to get the correct output. I'm sure my error is pretty simple if someone could just help me understand, thanks!

```
/*This program will allow a user to enter information into the zoo
or search by animal for the type of food it eats*/

import java.util.Scanner;

class zoo {
    //create array
    static String[][] animalFood;

    String[][] addArray(int x) {

    animalFood = new String[x][2];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   //loop through array and add amount of items user chose
    for (int row = 0; row < animalFood.length; row++){
        System.out.print("Enter an animal name: ");
        animalFood[row][0] = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the food the animal eats: ");
        animalFood[row][1] = in.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Thank you for adding information to the zoo!");
        System.out.println("You entered the following information: ");

        //loop through and print the informationa added
        for(int i = 0; i < animalFood.length; i++)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j < animalFood[i].length; j++)
           {
            System.out.print(animalFood[i][j]);
            if(j < animalFood[i].length - 1) System.out.print(" - ");
             }
            System.out.println();
}
       //prompt the user to search or quit
       System.out.println("Please enter the name of the animal to search for or Q to quit: ");
          String animalName = in.nextLine();
        animalName = animalName.toUpperCase();
        if(animalName.equals("Q")){
         System.out.println("Thanks for using the program!");
        }
        else {
           searchArray(animalName);
        }

         return animalFood;

}

String[][] searchArray(String name) {

   String matchResult = "There was no " + name + " found in the zoo!"; 
   String itemToMatch = name.toUpperCase();
   String arrayItem = "";
   String food = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < animalFood.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < animalFood.length; j++) {
         arrayItem = animalFood[i][j];
         arrayItem = arrayItem.toUpperCase();
         if(arrayItem.equals(itemToMatch)){ 
            matchResult = "The animal " + name + " was found in the zoo! It eats " + animalFood[j];        
         }
         else {
            //nothing found
         }      

      }
    }
    System.out.println(matchResult);
    if (food != null) {
    System.out.println(food);
    }
    return animalFood;
}

//constructor
public zoo() {

}

//overloaded constructor
public zoo(int x) {

   int number = x;
   animalFood = addArray(x);
}

//method to get users choice
public static int menu() {

    int selection;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please make a choice in the menu below");
    System.out.println("-------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("1 - Add animals and the food they eat.");
    System.out.println("2 - Search for an animal in the zoo.");
    System.out.println("3 - Exit the program");

    selection = input.nextInt();
    return selection;    
}

//main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create a new object
    zoo myZoo = new zoo();

    //variables and scanner
    int userChoice;
    int numberAnimals;
    String animalName = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //call the menu
    userChoice = menu();

    //actions based on user choice
    if (userChoice == 1) {
        System.out.println("How many animals would you like to enter information for?");
        numberAnimals = input.nextInt();
        myZoo.addArray(numberAnimals);
    }

    if (userChoice == 2) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the animal to search for: ");
        animalName = input.nextLine();
        myZoo.searchArray(animalName);
    }

    if (userChoice == 3) {
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the program!");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your problem is in `searchArray`. Your nested `for` loops are iterating over the size of only one dimension of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < animalFood.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < animalFood.length; j++) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Replace `animalFood.length` with `animalFood[i].length`, like you did correctly in the `addArray` method.

**EDIT**

It also looks like your output method is incorrect.

```
matchResult = "The animal " + name + " was found in the zoo! It eats " + animalFood[j];
```

In this line, `animalFood[j]` should be `animalFood[i][j]`. The strange output you're seeing is Java's attempt at converting an array into a String.

**2nd Edit**

After examining the `addArray` method, it seems I've made an incorrect assumption about your array. It appears your array is structured such that each index has 2 items, the animal, and its food. So it looks like so:

animalFood[0][0] = 'Cat'
animalFood[0][1] = 'Cat food'
animalFood[1][0] = 'Dog'
animalFood[1][1] = 'Dog food'
etc.

If this is the case, then you're going to want to change your loop to only iterate over the outer index. This means removing the inner for loop inside of `searchArray`. Then, you're only going to compare the first index of the inner array to the item you want to match, and if there's a match, then the food will be the second index. I'll leave implementation up to you (since this looks like a homework question). If something I've said here sounds wrong, let me know.

Comment: I had tried this previously and still receive some akward output: `The animal DOG was found in the zoo! It eats [Ljava.lang.String;@33909752
`

Comment: After reading the edit, I've tried that as well. It only displays the animal and not the food value though, I'm so lost: `The animal CAT was found in the zoo! It eats Cat`

Comment: do you think the array isn't being stored properly with the output I'm getting?

Comment: If I do that, removing the inner loop and the variable j, I get an error stating `incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String
         arrayItem = animalFood[i];` am I going about that wrong? Thank you so much for trying to help!

Comment: @javamatrix Your `arrayItem` should be `animalFood[i][0]` since that's where the animal's name is.  When you've matched the name and want the food, use `animalFood[i][1]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why I couldn't figure that out! Answer accepted, really appreciate it!